# Building a google analytics domain hash

Tags: google-analytics

I am creating my own GA library to build a url to the tracking pixel myself since I need to use GA in a cookie-less environment.  But I am stuck on create the domain hash for the cookie format.

In this cookie:

```
__utma=126394024.179004532335319200.1247654493.1260769004.1260878051.7
```

The first segment `126394024` is apparently a "domain hash", and while many sites seem to show how it's used, I cant actually figure out how to generate it from a domain.  Is this only done by an internal process on google servers that is unknown to the rest of the world?  Or is there a way I can hash the domain name myself to produce this token?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language are you building it for?

Comment: Javascript.  It's going into a system that has to work from a file:// url, which sadly does not support cookies.  And ga.js requires cookies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does this work?
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=626b0e277aaedc3c&hl=en

```
function hash(d){
var a=1,c=0,h,o;
if(d){
a=0;
for(h=d["length"]-1;h>=0;h--){
o=d.charCodeAt(h);
a=(a<<6&268435455)+o+(o<<14);
c=a&266338304;
a=c!=0?a^c>>21:a
}
}
return a
}
```

Have not verified it myself

Comment: Awesome, matches a ga.js test run perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

C# version of the above if anyone wants it:

```
    string hash(string d)
    {
        int a = 1;
        int c = 0;
        int h;
        int o;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(d))
        {
            a = 0;
            for (h = d.Length - 1; h >= 0; h--)
            {
                o = d[h];
                a = (a << 6 & 268435455) + o + (o << 14);
                c = a & 266338304;
                a = c != 0 ? a ^ c >> 21 : a;
            }
        }
        return a.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Java version. This could be useful to anyone needing a Hive UDF. The tricky parts of the translation are the operator precedence of bitwise xor, and the technique of getting at the Unicode.
The class definition has been left out in the interest of brevity.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

static int domain_hash(String s) {
    List<Integer> d = get_string_charCodes(s);
    int a=0,c=0,h,o;
    if (d.size() == 0) {
        return(1);
    }
    for(h = d.size()-1; h >= 0; h--) {
        o = d.get(h);
        a = ((a << 6) & 268435455) + o + (o << 14);
        c = a & 266338304;
        if (c != 0) {
            a = a^(c>>21);
        }
    }
    return(a);
}

static List<Integer> get_string_charCodes(String s) {
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int length = s.length(), codepoint, offset;
    for(offset = 0; offset < length; offset += Character.charCount(codepoint)) {
        codepoint = s.codePointAt(offset);
        l.add(codepoint);
    }
    return(l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but I couldn't find it elsewhere, so for what it's worth here is a PHP version. It works for me, so hopefully it's up to snuff for others.

```
function hash($d){
    $a = 1;
    $c = 0;     
    if ( $d ){
        $a = 0;
        for ( $h = strlen($d)-1; $h >= 0; $h-- ){
            $o = ord($d[$h]);
            $a = (($a<<6)&268435455)+$o+($o<<14);
            $c = $a&266338304;
            $a = ( $c != 0 )? $a^($c>>21) : $a;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```